# html5 boilerplate w3c validator error

Tags: html, w3c, validation, boilerplate

I was checking [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) out in W3C Validator using a html5 test and it gave this error

```
Line 8, Column 64: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

What should the value be to pass this test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, validation doesn't mean anything – html isn't XML, and hence doesn't have a schema like that to validate on.

Assuming you know that validation is pointless, and are treating it as a linter to help pick up errors, this error is an error. The `X-` prefix means that this is vendor specific, in this case it's for IE (meaning render in the best version), and for Chrome Frame (the 1 means on).

It's not invalid.

Comment: Ok so it won't be a problem to leave this as is then I take it? and what does this mean in layman's terms "html isn't XML, and hence doesn't have a schema like that to validate on."

Comment: Leaving it like this is fine. The point is that HTML doesn't have any real way to programmatically validate it – unlike XML (which people thought it was going to be with XHTML), the rules for HTML are well defined and clear, but many things are optional. Ensuring that it produces the correct DOM Tree (i.e. the browser renders it correctly) is the only way to decide if something is correct. The w3c validator will help you detect errors, but can only really be treated as advice generated by a computer. If you get hundreds of errors, it's worth digging into why, but that doesn't mean much.

Comment: Ok I get what you're saying now, thanks for the explanation Rich, much appreciated.

Comment: @JizboJonez Although HTML isn't XML, it definitely does have a schema that you can validate it with, it is just a very complicated one.  In this case the w3c validator as far as I know is incorrect as marking this an error is incorrect.  But in any case, it's safe to ignore.